# Send JSON in PUT request

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

The following passes (taken from https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_request/, removed `.toJSON` as it did not exist), but does not add an entry to the REST API:

```
class TestREST extends Simulation {
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5000") // Here is the root for all relative URLs

  val scn = scenario("UploadMany") // A scenario is a chain of requests and pauses
    .exec(http("request_1")
      .put("/")
      .body(StringBody("""{
            "text":"lalala", "title": "hello world", "date": "12346"}"""))
      .check(status.is(200))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol))

}
```

How do you add JSON data to a `.put` request with Gatling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had removed the `.asJSON` from the example at https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_request/, as it failed. This method was renamed to (capitalized) `.asJson` in 3.1, so the following change fixes it:

```
  .body(StringBody("""{
        "text":"lalala", "title": "hello world", "date": "12346"}""")).asJson
```